# How do I model a problem with part of the information is missing?

Tags: probability

I am now currently having a problem that require solving, and I am currently having problems trying to fit it into a Mathematical model.

Suppose there are multiple lists (assuming more than a handful of them and each of them is independent) of shops in the town that are known to sell imiated/fake products, and the lists are not exhaustive (there are missing entries that are not reported, hence not entered into the list). Now, given a name of shop, I am interested to know the probability of it being one of those shop.

I tried fitting this with Bayes theorem but doesn't seem right, this is what I was thinking:

- Hypothesis, H = bad shop
- Prior, P(H) <- this is what I really want
- Evidence, E = a list of shops
- Posterior P(H|E) = probability of a shop being bad given it exists in the list
- likelihood P(E|H) = probability of a shop being listed, given it is bad <- I do not have this information
- marginal likelihood, P(E) = probability of a shop being listed

But I really don't find the model suitable, as I don't have at least half the information (namely, known good shops).

How else can I tackle the problem? In what direction should I continue my research and reading?

Comment: The problem with this question and the proposed solutions seems to be that some essential information is not observable in the data. As stated by Gijs, one can make assumptions about the probability that a bad shop or a good shop make it on the list, but just based on the lists there is no way to check (or update, in a Bayesian manner) these assumptions. This would require additional information, checking whether some shops on the lists (or not listed) are indeed bad.

Comment: posted an answer below based on the accepted answer
yes, i am aware of the missing information, hence i was struggling to find a model that fits the scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model you want to create here is about how shops make it onto the various lists. For example, a very simple model would be, each shop that is good has 0 probability to make it onto any list, and if it is selling fake than it has a probability of $p$ making it onto any list. Let's assume you have 2 lists. Then, if a shop is on a list you are sure it is selling fake stuff. If it's not, to calculate the probability of it selling fakes you also need a prior probability of any shop selling fake stuff (let's call it $q$). With that information you can apply Bayes Theorem to obtain the probability of a shop not on any list actually selling fakes.

But you will always need an estimate of $p$ before any real number will come out of this. If you don't have that, you can never say anything quantative of shops not on a list. This makes sense, because you need to know how precise the lists are in order to interpret the information. Perhaps you can estimate this precision from the number of shops on lists and the base rate of bad shops (which is $q$ and needed as well)?

Comment: i don't have an estimate of prior, so i am thinking of collecting all the queries, and over time derive an estimation of it by calculating (the number of queries that found the shop in list / total number of queries) by assuming that the queries follow the same distribution of of the population (?)

Comment: what if I want to model such that if the site appears on more lists (assuming I have more than a handful of them), the chance of it being bad is higher?

Comment: For estimate of $p$ I would say use maybe (total number of listed shops / estimated number of bad shops), so let's say you have 100 shops appearing on a list, but you think there's going to be 1000 shops bad in total, use 10%. If you want to have a model that is more convinced if more lists include a shop, you will need to allow a probability $r$ that a list wrongly includes a shop. That's going to be an additional parameter.

Comment: hmm the list is always growing and changing, so we do not have a total number, and the content is always changing, so we only refer to the lists whenever we are being asked, so it is somewhat similar to an information retrieval/search situation but I am looking for a method to return a number from a fixed range, preferably [0..1], which denotes how bad it is

Comment: while reading on the topic, i came across some tutorials on how bayes theorem is about updating the probability, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZCskBpHWyk so i can now start with a prior, and then calculate the posterior, and then update the prior as I progress to check the same shop against another list?

just to be clear, so according to the model you proposed, if my list has 100 shop names, probability of a given shop name being listed is P(listed) = 1/100, and not being listed is P(~listed) = 1 - (1/100), right?

Comment: So the model is defined by $H$=Shop is bad, and $E$=shop is in the list, am I doing this correctly?

Comment: so prior $P(H)$ = some estimation of probability of bad shop vs good shop, e.g. count of spam / count of queries; $P(E)$ = 1 / total # of entries in the list we are currently inspecting; $P(E|H)$ = total count of current list / total count of all list. Then i have a very rough estimate of probability of any given shop is bad, need to then figure out how to calculate the actual probability of a specific shop is bad

Comment: You will indeed need the Bayes Theorem. You can combine the probabilities, so the updating for each list is probably not the most straightforward way to think about it. 

The probability of a shop being listed you need, for this model, is, for a good shop, for each list, there is a probability $r$ that the list will wrongly include it. And for a bad shop, it's $p$. Both are parameters of the model, you will need to make some assumptions about them.

Comment: The way forward for you is to put in some numbers I think. So let's say a list will put on a bad shop with probability 65% and a good shop with probability 5%. And the probability of a shop being bad is 10%. Then, if you know a shop is on the list, you can calculate the probability of it being bad by applying Bayes rule. You can also calculate other probabilities of interest. First try this with one list. Then if you can get it to work, expand to more lists. If you can't, perhaps ask another question with the specific model and numbers I proposed.

Comment: thanks for the help (:

Comment: I posted an answer based on what I understand from your answer and the discussion above, am I doing it correctly? (not super urgent tho)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the nature of the lists of shops that are non-exhaustive, and they keep being updated without informing (so we do not have an up to date exhaustive list from them, if we want to know if a shop is listed, we have to ask), so this is the best I can do, with help from @Gijs

Suppose

query = an attempt to check by providing the name of a shop

$H$ = a shop is graded BAD

$E$ = a shop is listed in a given list

therefore, we assume the parameters for [Bayes rule](https://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/%7Enorman/BBNs/Bayes_rule.htm)

$P(H|E) = \frac{P(E|H)P(H)}{P(E)}$

by

(Initial) Prior, $P(H) = P(H) = \frac{\text{total number of queries that are found listed}}{\text{total number of queries}}$

then for each list that contains the query, we check to update the prior

Marginal likelihood, $P(E) = \frac{\text{total number of entries in the list}}{\text{total number of queries}}$

Likelihood, $P(E|H) = \frac{\text{total number of entries in the list}}{\text{total number of queries that are found listed}}$

We will return the last posterior, $P(H|E)$ after going through all the lists. However, if a shop is not listed in any of the lists we have, we will return $1 - P(H)$

The answer will likely be a bit off initially (so I most likely have to replace the parameters with a temporary estimated number, or make up a number somehow) but eventually the model should return more sensible figure with enough queries.

Comment: In this answer, what is a "query"?

Comment: query is the name of a shop where we are interested in finding out the probability